# Looping a Multi Dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I encountered this kind of array in my tasks. It's a multi dimensional array.
In the form, I have this,

> particular[particular][]
>   particular[percentage][]
>   particular[remarks][]

So what I'm doing is, I'm getting request

> $inputs = $request->all();

this returns

```
 array:3 [▼
    "particular" => array:3 [▶]
    "percentage" => array:3 [▶]
    "remarks" => array:3 [▶]
 ]
```

inside, each of them have

```
 array:3 [▼
     "particular" => array:3 [▼
         0 => "11"
         1 => "22"
         2 => "33"
     ] 
     "percentage" => array:3 [▼
         0 => "11"
         1 => "22"
         2 => "33"
     ]
     "remarks" => array:3 [▼
         0 => "na1"
         1 => "na2"
         2 => "na3"
      ]
 ]
```

I tried looping it

> ```
> foreach ($inputs as $input) {
>      dd($input);
> }
> ```

but I only get the first one "particular" => array:3 [▶]

What I'm after is, I need to save those value in database

```
 $particular = new Particular;
 $particular->particular = particular;
 $particular->percentage = percentage;
 $particular->remarks = remarks;
 $particular->save();
```

Comment: `dd` meand `dump and DIE` so your script __dies__ on first iteration.

Answer (score 3):

`dd` means "dump and DIE" so your script **dies** on first iteration.

You can:

```
$particular = new Particular;
$particular->particular = $inputs['particular'];
$particular->percentage = $inputs['percentage'];
$particular->remarks = $inputs['remarks'];
$particular->save();
```

Also, if you need to just dump something - there's a `dump` function (surprise!):

```
foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    dump($input);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find a solution. I don't know if this is the proper, but for now atleast it work for me.

```
    $array1 = $request->particular;
    $array2 = $request->percentage;
    $array3 = $request->remarks;

    $merge = [$array1, $array2, $array3];

    foreach ($merge[0] as $key => $value) {
        $particular = new Particular;
        $particular->particular = $merge[0][$key];
        foreach ($merge[1] as $x => $y) {
            $particular->percentage = $merge[1][$key];

        }
        foreach ($merge[2] as $i => $d) {
            $particular->remarks = $merge[2][$key];

        }
        $particular->report_id = $report->id;
        $particular->save();
    }
```